# Custom tags to place permanent and temporary CSS on page

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have a single-page web-application and am planning to add and remove CSS `<style></style>` tags dynamically, for pages that need and don't need certain styles. I don't want to have styles overlap or have to debug weird problems, so for simplicity's sake (and perhaps even faster rendering) I want to remove stylesheets that don't pertain to the current view.

I was thinking of using a structure like this:

```
    <html>
    <head>

     <!-- this linked stylesheet is for all pages, so it is non-ephemeral -->
     <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css">

    <special> <!-- this block houses ephemeral stylesheets -->

    <!-- remove all the stylesheets from this block everytime there's a view  --> 
    <!-- change and then add only the stylesheets that pertain to the current view here as well -->

     <style class='temporaryCSS"> xyz </style>

    </special>

    </head>

    <body>
    </body>
    </html>
```

so basically, there could be one particular/special block where I remove all CSS  tags on each view change. The nice thing about the custom block is that it quickly designates to the eye where the temporary/ephemeral stylesheets reside. So my question is, **(1)** can I create my own tag for this, like `<special>` or should I use a `<div>` with an id (seems like a bad idea because divs are for visuals not metadata) or should I just give all the temporary CSS  tags a class attribute like "temporaryCSS"? **(2)** Should I put the temporary  sheets in the `<head>` or the `<body>`? **(3)** perhaps I am doing this all wrong?

Anybody tried something like this before?

The nice thing about using a class for the  tags is I could probably just use a jQuery selector and `.remove()` everything with that class.

Comment: Instead of deleting the CSS, you can just remove the CSS-class of the element that you suddently don't want styled any longer and leave the actual CSS-code alone. That's how it's done normally.

Comment: Downloading a single .css file, once, with all styles you're going to use in it will be far more efficient than adding and removing styles within the page. The one file will be transmitted _once_, and parsed _once_, and _cached_, while adding and removing will force the browser to re-download the style block, and re-parse the CSS over and over again, and _slow_ your rendering. _Think_ about your styles, _design_ your page structure. Your DOM layout shouldn't be an afterthought. CSS classes should describe _things_, not _looks_. Well designed CSS and DOM will not have "weird" problems.

Comment: @StephenP actually, I load the CSS once with RequireJS, using the text plugin, so the CSS is loaded only once; in other words I am not using AJAX repeatedly to retrieve the stylesheets from the server, I only do that once, no matter how many times I would ever add or remove the style tags. One downside of course is the time it takes to manipulate the DOM to add and remove style tags, but perhaps you can just make a style tag inactive or disable it. You shouldn't have to add or remove the whole thing from the DOM. Does this change your answer?

Comment: see my answer and let me know if you think it's accurate before I accept it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am answering my own question. The `<style>` tags probably should *not* be added and removed from the DOM dynamically because that's DOM churn. Instead, you can set the style tags to active or inactive / enabled / disabled as per:

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/style

It seems perfectly reasonable to want to 'add' and 'remove' styles on the fly.